# How to select droid sans condensed font?

Tags: android

I see that a [Driod Sans Condensed](http://www.droidfonts.com/info/droid-sans-condensed-fonts/) font is available on the android, but from what I can see the `android:typeface` attribute can only have the following values - `normal`, `sans`, `serif` and `monospace`.

Question is how do I select this "condensed" font? Also, it's not clear from the page which version onward is this font available.

**EDIT:**

I ran a test with two `TextView` objects having typefaces set to `normal` and `mono` respectively and as far as I can tell there's no difference between the two.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Droid Sans Condensed is not included in the SDK, but it's available for purchase:

- http://www.droidfonts.com/droidfonts
- http://www.ascenderfonts.com/font/handset-condensed-family.aspx

If you decide to buy it, you can use it in your app this way:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: This is a free font, do not pay for it.